# Prevent home (welcome file) URL from changing to full URL when submitting a JSF form

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, friendly-url

I've a welcome file

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>configurationClass.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

It is opening properly on start with url "http://127.0.0.1:8080/fav/".

Then in my page, i am having a sortable table which is calling to a method sortFavs() present in my class. And i am returning null from server method.

So url is changing to "http://127.0.0.1:8080/fav/configurationClass.xhtml"
Can i get the same output with previous url? How to do this without using any other lib like omnifaces or others ?

Comment: Download the source of framework/libt x (or y or z), copy the relevant sources to your project, rebuild and you are done... 

Or in other words: why not just use an external library (not sure OmniFaces can do this specific thing)

Comment: Is there any other way to do this? May be some mapping?

Comment: if 'some mapping'  can be a PrettyFaces config file then yes. Otherwise maybe if you have a reverse proxy in front that can help you, but I just use PrettyFaces

Comment: And btw, why is this a problem? You can always add an empty welcome file with a html meta redirext to the actual page. The url will then not change after sorting. Or use ajax sorting. It won't change then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />` to the command button/link. This way the POST request will be performed asynchronously instead of synchronously and the browser's address bar URL will stay the same all time.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with a non-ajax request? @BalusC

Comment: @rion18: If there was a way without 3rd party libraries, I'd have answered that. You could hack around with iframes, but that's plain ugly.